MetaMask eth_requestAccounts not retrieving wallet address after signing in
I’m integrating MetaMask into my Next.js app with wagmi, and I’m encountering an issue where after connecting to MetaMask, the wallet address isn’t retrieved immediately. The app asks for signing via MetaMask, but after signing, the wallet address isn’t available, and I need to click “Connect Wallet” again for the address to appear.
Here’s the code for connecting and signing in:
const onSignInWithCrypto = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Attempting to connect wallet...');

    if (!address) {
      const connector = connectors[0];
      if (!connector) throw new Error('No connectors found');
      await connect({ connector });
    }

    const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    const walletAddress = accounts[0];

    if (!walletAddress) {
      throw new Error('Failed to get the wallet address after connection');
    }

    console.log('Wallet connected with address:', walletAddress);

    const response = await fetch('/api/auth/generateNonce', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ publicAddress: walletAddress }),
    });

    const { nonce } = await response.json();
    const signature = await signMessage({ message: nonce });

    await signIn('crypto', {
      publicAddress: walletAddress,
      signedNonce: signature,
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during sign-in:', error.message);
  }
};

I’ve tried retrying address fetching, but it doesn’t work until the second attempt. After signing in MetaMask the first time, it fails to retrieve the address and displays an error: “Failed to get the wallet address after connection”.
Here are the steps leading up to the issue:
1.  Click “Connect Wallet” (MetaMask opens, signs in).
2.  Error appears: “Failed to get the wallet address after connection”.
3.  Clicking “Connect Wallet” again retrieves the address and works fine.

I suspect there’s a delay in MetaMask providing the wallet address, but I’m unsure how to handle this properly. Is there a better way to ensure MetaMask provides the address after signing in without needing to press “Connect Wallet” again?
Any advice or solutions would be appreciated!
